# Why did this company's net income significantly increase in 3rd quarter in 2020?

Tags: stocks, investing, balance-sheet

This is quarterly income statement for this company:

[image]

I want to know why this company's 3rd quarterly income increased from -4 to 896.
and how do I find out about the answer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which company? Please copy the relevant info into the question, otherwise this looks like spam / clickbait.

Comment: TROX, you can click it on 'This is quarterly income statement for this company'. I don't know how to post the picture to be seen in the question right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their Q3 2020 financial results [press release](https://investor.tronox.com/press-releases/press-releases-details/2020/Tronox-Reports-Third-Quarter-2020-Financial-Results/default.aspx)

> Net income of $902 million primarily due to the reversal of a portion
> of U.S. valuation allowance relating to net operating loss
> carryforwards resulting in a non-cash benefit of $895 million.